# Using an entire Symfony 2 app as a plugin for native php project?

Tags: php, symfony, modularity, user-management

I have an old project which I want to add user management to.

Symfony has the [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony2bundles.org/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) which makes user straightforward.

Is there a way to integrate Symfony in the old project so that I can benefit from the UserBundle?

Comment: have you already used FOSUserBundle in symfony2?

Comment: I've used it yes. There are some demos in github as well. Here's [one by Marcos Quesada](https://github.com/marcosQuesada/Symfony2--Sonata-Full---FOSUserBundle)

Answer (score 1):

This question is extremely hard to answer without specific details of the existing project. We have no idea how the project was constructed. Is it all spaghetti code? Is it MVC based? Is it using an existing framework?

If you're asking if somehow Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle can somehow be shoehorned into your project - I doubt it. A number of Symfony2's features can be used as stand alone libraries, but bundles, and therefore FOSUserBundle, are tightly coupled with Symfony2's MVC stack.

You need to ask yourself if you're willing to rewrite your project using Symfony2. If you're not, then you need to find another solution for user management that will work with what you've already got setup.

Comment: I didn't provide details because I want to know whether I can plug Symfony in any project. I imagine this is possible if I can boot symfony and then programmatically call a Symfony action.